# import silently kills thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I have a simple program `Base.py` that tests if `import` is able to throw an exception when the module does not exist.

```
# Base.py
import threading, os, time
import_is_working = False

class Launch(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        global import_is_working
        try:
            print "Yes, it got into the 'try' block"
            import NON_EXISTENT_MODULE
            assert False
        except:
            print "Great, your python language is working"
            import_is_working = True
Launch()
for i in range(500):
    time.sleep(0.01)
    if import_is_working:
        break
if not import_is_working:
    print "Your import is not working."
    os._exit(4)
```

Sometimes I like to use this code in another module `Main.py`:

```
# Main.py
import Base
```

Surprisingly, it doesn't work when I run it that way:

```
max% python Base.py
Yes, it got into the 'try' block
Great, your python language is working
max% python Main.py
Yes, it got into the 'try' block
Your import is not working.
max%
```

This happens in Ubuntu, and in a clean CentOS 7.3 install too.

Comment: Just a recommendation: whenever you're catching an exception, add the exception (and possibly the stack trace as well) to your reporting scheme. e.g. ... except Exception as e: ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into the "import lock".

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#importing-in-threaded-code) mentions the limitations in importing during threads, you're violating the first one (emphasis mine):

> While the import machinery is thread-safe, there are two key
>   restrictions on threaded imports due to inherent limitations in the
>   way that thread-safety is provided:
>
> Firstly, other than in the main module, **an import should not have the side effect of spawning a new thread and then waiting for that
>   thread in any way**. Failing to abide by this restriction can lead to a
>   deadlock if the spawned thread directly or indirectly attempts to
>   import a module.
>
> Secondly, all import attempts must be completed before the interpreter starts shutting itself down. This can be most easily
>   achieved by only performing imports from non-daemon threads created
>   through the threading module. Daemon threads and threads created
>   directly with the thread module will require some other form of
>   synchronization to ensure they do not attempt imports after system
>   shutdown has commenced. Failure to abide by this restriction will lead
>   to intermittent exceptions and crashes during interpreter shutdown (as
>   the late imports attempt to access machinery which is no longer in a
>   valid state).

Comment: Thank you. This answers my specific question about why my program was hanging. I had not known about this import lock. Of course, this leads to more questions and I will be opening new questions about how best to avoid this problem in various situations. I do still feel that we should clean up the example to be a real example that follows best practices (this problem only showed up when I [started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326059/) using `setuptools`, but it just took longer to isolate that case). But if we can't edit the question, then, well, saving the world can wait.